# Can I check command line arguments one by one in a loop?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to make my program check the command line arguemnts inputted by one by one in a loop, so that it moves from an operation to the next.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("One argument expected.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    createLog("log.txt");
    if (strcmp(argv[i++], "create") == 0)
    {
        createFile();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "copy") == 0)
    {
        copyFile();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "delete") == 0)
    {
        deleteFile();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "show") == 0)
    {
        readFile();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "append") == 0)
    {
        appendLine();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "deleteLine") == 0)
    {
        deleteInsert(True); //The argument isDelete to check if we wanted to delete or insert
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "insertLine") == 0)
    {
        deleteInsert(False); //The argument isDelete to check if we wanted to delete or insert
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "showLine") == 0)
    {
        showLine();
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i++], "exit") == 0)
    {
        printf("Closing program");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid argument");
    }
}
```

I treated like a loop where the `i` keeps on increasing every time it checks it. I tried using an infinte do while loop before my if else statments but it ended up giving me a segmentation fault.

My program is supposed to create, read, append lines, show lines, insert and delete lines as well. Is it possible to do what I want? Or should I change my approach?

Comment: You don't have a loop. You're incrementing the index in each test. So you're checking if the first argument is `create`, then you're checking if the second argument is `copy`, then if the third argument is `delete`, and so on.

Comment: Yes you can use a loop.  It is normal to do so.  But don't keep incrementing `i` as you do.

Comment: You may only increment `i` after you compared the option with all possible commands.

Comment: `i keeps on increasing every time it checks it`, you do realize it check it only once? if the first `if` is true, none of the `else if` will ever be evaluated.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The question is "Can I check command line arguments one by one in a loop?". If it makes sense for an application to have multiple arguments "create copy delete" in a single command line, well that's another story.

Comment: Please clarify if your program accepts only _one_  argument or _several arguments_. `if(argc == 1)` suggests it supports only _one_ argument, therefore a loop is not necessary.

Comment: @Jabberwocky argc==1 when there are no arguments, because `argv[0]` is the executable name.

Comment: Thank you!! I am not sure why i was incrementing it everytime tbh, and it originally supported one argument beside the file name for example i would have writte that in the temrinal ```./filename create``` but i want it to support multiple ones so it keeps on checking every argument writtten

Comment: @sagi Yea i just realised it does. Even if it is in a loop, and even if i only increment the ```i``` at the end. Is there a way i can do what was intended?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make something slightly faster and more maintainable, like this (regard this as pseudo code because I haven't compiled nor tested):

```
typedef struct
{
  const char* command;
  void (*action)(void)
} arg_command_t;

const arg_command_t commands[] =  //sorted in alphabetic order!
{
  { "copy",   copyFile   },
  { "create", createFile },
  ...
};

...

for(size_t i=1; i<argc; i++)
{
  const arg_command_t key = { argv[i], NULL };
  const arg_command_t* result;
  result = bsearch(&key, 
                   commands, 
                   sizeof commands / sizeof *commands,
                   sizeof *commands,
                   comp_func); 
  if(result != NULL)
  {
    result->action();
  }
}
```

Then implement `comp_func` like a wrapper around `strcmp` checking the string member of each struct item.

Comment: I'm afraid this is somewhat beyond the scope of the OP, even if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I wouldn't assume as much, one just has to study how `bsearch` works and that's about it.

Comment: Forget my comments, I was confused by the txt `"One argument expected.\n"`. I'll delete them. I'l delete this one in a while too.